# Hierarchical aggregation on path hierarchy tokens in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index with hierarchical data. Here are the example documents from my index `locations_hierarchy`:

```
{
    "_index" : "locations_hierarchy",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "category_path" : "Art Gallery, Paintings, Case 1"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "locations_hierarchy",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "2",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "category_path" : "Display Gallery, Small Worlds, Case 1, Shelf 2"
    }
}
```

Here's the aggregation I want to achieve:

```
{
          "key" : "Art Gallery",
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "category_sub" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "Paintings",
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "category_sub_sub" : {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                  "buckets" : [
                    {
                      "key" : "Case 1",
                      "doc_count" : 1
                    },
                    {
                      "key" : "Case 3",
                      "doc_count" : 1
                    }
                  ]
                }
}
```

I have tried aggregating them by using include and exclude in the aggregation query but it is quite a manual procedure and it won't work for a case where I don't know the number of levels in the hierarchy.

Is there any possible solution for hierarchical aggregation on a path hierarchy token field in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

### First of all, I recommend having `hierarchical category fields` in your data. You can achieve it by parsing your data during ingestion.

I found a method to achieve the results with the current data you have, it's not exactly what you want but hope it helps!

```
POST /test_aggs_hierarchy/_bulk
{"index": {"_id": "1"}}
{"category_path": "Art Gallery, Paintings, Case 1"}
{"index": {"_id": "2"}}
{"category_path": "Art Gallery, Sculptures, Case 1"}
{"index": {"_id": "3"}}
{"category_path": "Display Gallery, Small Worlds, Case 1, Shelf 2"}
{"index": {"_id": "4"}}
{"category_path": "Display Gallery, Small Worlds, Case 2, Shelf 1"}
```

---

```
POST /test_aggs_hierarchy/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "hierarchy": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
            def path = doc['category_path.keyword'].value;
            if (path != null) {
              def tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(path, ',');
              def levels = [];
              while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                levels.add(tokenizer.nextToken().trim());
              }
              return levels;
            }
            return [];
          """
        },
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sub_hierarchy": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category_path.keyword",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

### The result:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "category_top": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Case 1",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "category_sub": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Art Gallery, Paintings, Case 1",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "Art Gallery, Sculptures, Case 1",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "Display Gallery, Small Worlds, Case 1, Shelf 2",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Art Gallery",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "category_sub": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Art Gallery, Paintings, Case 1",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "Art Gallery, Sculptures, Case 1",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Display Gallery",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "category_sub": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Display Gallery, Small Worlds, Case 1, Shelf 2",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "Display Gallery, Small Worlds, Case 2, Shelf 1",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Small Worlds",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "category_sub": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Display Gallery, Small Worlds, Case 1, Shelf 2",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "Display Gallery, Small Worlds, Case 2, Shelf 1",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Case 2",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "category_sub": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Display Gallery, Small Worlds, Case 2, Shelf 1",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Paintings",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "category_sub": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Art Gallery, Paintings, Case 1",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Sculptures",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "category_sub": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Art Gallery, Sculptures, Case 1",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Shelf 1",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "category_sub": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Display Gallery, Small Worlds, Case 2, Shelf 1",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Shelf 2",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "category_sub": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Display Gallery, Small Worlds, Case 1, Shelf 2",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```